# Unity crashes when using dijkstra's algorithm with different starting points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, routes

This is my first time asking a question here, so please forgive me if I make any mistakes.

I'm currently using Unity 2019.1.14f1 on Windows 10 Enterprise with an Intel Xeon E5-1650 v4 with 32.0 GB RAM, GeForce GTX 1080 with the latest drivers.

To give a little context to the problem, I have a unity scene set up which has a bunch of objects with the *NavLinkProxy* class and *NavNodeProxy* class that store some data. These are used for generating routes, specifically using Dijkstra's algorithm. Below is the code I used:

```
private static void DijkstraSearch(VenueManager venueManager, NavNodeProxy start, NavNodeProxy end)
{
    // Priority queue
    var pQueue = new BinaryHeap<NavNodeProxy>();

    // Set cost of start node to 0
    start._NavNodeInfo.MinCostToStart = 0;

    // Add start node to priority queue
    pQueue.Add(start);

    do
    {
        // Remove node on top of heap and set it as node value
        var node = pQueue.Remove();

        List<NavLinkProxy> nodeLinks = venueManager._ActiveNavLinks.FindAll(result => (result._NavLinkInfo.n1 == node) || (result._NavLinkInfo.n2 == node));

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeLinks.Count; i++)
        {
            NavNodeProxy connectingNode;

            if (nodeLinks[i]._NavLinkInfo.n1._NavNodeInfo.id == node._NavNodeInfo.id)
                connectingNode = nodeLinks[i]._NavLinkInfo.n2;
            else
                connectingNode = nodeLinks[i]._NavLinkInfo.n1;

            if (connectingNode._NavNodeInfo.Visited)
                continue;

            if (connectingNode._NavNodeInfo.MinCostToStart == Mathf.Infinity || node._NavNodeInfo.MinCostToStart + nodeLinks[i]._NavLinkInfo.horizontalLength < connectingNode._NavNodeInfo.MinCostToStart)
            {
                connectingNode._NavNodeInfo.MinCostToStart = node._NavNodeInfo.MinCostToStart + nodeLinks[i]._NavLinkInfo.horizontalLength;
                connectingNode._NavNodeInfo.NearestToStart = node;
                if (!pQueue.heapList.Contains(connectingNode))
                    pQueue.Add(connectingNode);
            }
        }
        node._NavNodeInfo.Visited = true;

        if (node == end)
            return;
    } while (pQueue.heapList.Any());
}
```

The route is generated normally at first and works perfectly fine if I change the position of the *end* as well.

However, when I change the position of the *start* and try to generate a route, Unity hangs up, usually remaining completely non-responsive and forcing me to force close it.

I have tried swapping the start and end node objects in the scene and repeated the above steps to get the exact same results. Besides this I'm not very sure what could be happening to give me this result.

**Edit:** Edited the post with the correct code.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code to see what is happening? I see that `startNode` is never used in your function? I would guess that it is stuck in an infinite loop if you pass in a value for `endNode` where `NearestToStart` is never null.

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy Thanks for pointing that out, that was a redundancy I didn't notice. Another thing I didn't notice was that I put up the wrong code entirely. Apologies for that, I will update the question with the correct code in a minute.

Comment: Where is this method called from? is it in update and trying to run every frame perhaps?

Comment: @BugFinder No, the way I've currently implemented it, the DijkstraSearch method is called only when the user clicks a UI Button in the scene.

Comment: if you compile it up and run it, are there any useful hints in the log file?

Comment: Do you need to set `connectingNode._NavNodeInfo.Visited` to true at some point? I would still guess that its stuck in an infinite loop where the connecting node is removed from the list at the start of the loop at readded again at `pQueue.Add(connectingNode)`. Try stepping though it with the debugger, im sure you will see the problem

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy `connectingNode_NavNodeInfo.Visited` checks whether the node other than the active one has already been visited. If it hasn't, it is added to pQueue to undergo the same process. The algorithm is a basic implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm so the logic is definitely sound.

I can confirm that visited nodes don't get added to pQueue again after checking it while debugging.

Comment: @BugFinder I did, unfortunately, I've not gotten anything there either. It definitely behaves like some kind of infinite loop, but I can't pinpoint which loop in my code may be causing this.